# How to write a function that returns sum of numeric array from unknown type?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I need to write a function that sums up a numeric array that i dont know its type.
the function can recieve the size of the array and the size of each variable.
I've been told that I should use a void pointer but I cant see how to do it.
BTW I cant use macros.
thanks!

Comment: When `float` and `int` are the same size I think that it can not be distinguished under that condition.

Comment: A `float` and an `int` have different representations; you can't tell which is which from size alone.

Comment: The obious solution: write *multiple* functions. Could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? C doesn't have much support for "generics", only something usable with macros (generic selection). It **can't** have more support as type information isn't present in a compiled C program.

Comment: What is the return type of the function?

Comment: @Yakalolo  In any case you need to write as many functions as there are used array types and the type of the accumulator. :)

Comment: Can you pass a callback function (*a la* `qsort`) in addition to the array size and element size?

Comment: I dont think so, but if I could how would it help?

Answer (score 2):

The entire exercise sounds stupid, to be honest.

You'd need to use a function that has a interface roughly similar to [`qsort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html):

```
void calculate_sum(const void  *ptr,
                   const size_t size,
                   const size_t num,
                   void        *sum,
                   void       (*sum_func)(void *, const void *))
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        sum_func(sum, (void *)((char *)ptr + size * i));
}
```

The caller would still need a summing function for each type, say

```
void sum_int(void *acc, const void *val)
{
    *(int *)acc += *(const int *)val;
}

void sum_float(void *acc, const void *val)
{
    *(float *)acc += *(const float *)val;
}
```

Let's say a caller has a couple of arrays, say

```
float  fdata[50];
double ddata[40];
```

To calculate their sums, one would need to

```
float  fsum;
double dsum;

fsum = 0.0f;
calculate_sum(fdata, sizeof fdata[0], 50, &fsum, sum_float);

dsum = 0.0;
calculate_sum(ddata, sizeof ddata[0], 40, &dsum, sum_double);
```

That interface works well for things like `qsort()` -- although even `qsort()`'s would benefit from caller being able to pass a third parameter, a `void *`, pased to the comparison function. In my opinion, a sort exercise works very well for this kind of interface, especially when used with a small `struct` of some kind.

Here, I think the exercise steers learners in the wrong direction: this is not the correct interface for arithmetic operations. It produces Enterprise code, overly complicated and slow, designed for job security; not readable, maintainable, good code.

Arithmetic stuff, like summing, in my opinion *requires* dedicated functions.  That does not mean you have to copy-paste a lot of code, though; we can use the preprocessor for our advantage here.

Let's look at how one could implement the summing using C11 `_Generic` semantics:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* For  size_t  type */

#define DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(type, funcname)             \
    type funcname (const type *data, size_t count)  \
    {                                               \
        const type  *ends = data + count;           \
        type         sum  = 0;                      \
        while (data < ends)                         \
            sum += *(data++);                       \
        return sum;                                 \
    }

DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(float,   float_sum);
DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(double, double_sum);
DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(short,   short_sum);
DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(int,       int_sum);
DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(long,     long_sum);

#define array_sum(array, count) _Generic((array)[0],                \
     float:  float_sum((const float  *)(array), (size_t)(count)),   \
    double: double_sum((const double *)(array), (size_t)(count)),   \
     short:  short_sum((const short  *)(array), (size_t)(count)),   \
       int:    int_sum((const int    *)(array), (size_t)(count)),   \
      long:   long_sum((const long   *)(array), (size_t)(count))  )
```

The `DEFINE_SUM_FUNC(type, funcname)` macro evaluates to a function definition. The function calculates the sum of array elements. (This implementation uses the pointer approach.)

Now, if you have the same two arrays as before, `float fdata[50];` and `double ddata[40];`, you can just call

```
fsum = array_sum(fdata, 50);
dsum = array_sum(ddata, 40);
```

Note that `array_sum()` works for both arrays and pointers. That is, if you had `float *fdata;`, or `const double *ddata;`, the above two lines would work just fine.

In pre-C11 code, you can drop the `array_sum()` macro, and call the type-specific function yourself:

```
fsum = float_sum(fdata, 50);
dsum = double_sum(ddata, 40);
```

(GCC does provide an extension, `__builtin_types_compatible_p()` that one can use to construct the `array_sum()` macro even without `_Generic()`.)